# How to add the component which allows adding an article to a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I need to add the ListArticle component which allows adding an article to a list.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function ListArticle() {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  const [designation, setDesignation] = useState("");
  const [prix, setPrix] = useState(0);
  const [Article, setArticle] = useState([]);
  const handlerOnChangeId = (e) => {
    setId(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlerOnChangeDesignation = (e) => {
    setDesignation(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlerOnChangePrix = (e) => {
    setPrix(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlerAddArticle = (e) => {
    setArticle(e.target.Article);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="list">
        <h2 className="title">Ajout d'un Article</h2>
        <div>
          <label>Id:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={handlerOnChangeId} value={id} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>designation:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={handlerOnChangeDesignation} value={designation}/>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
        <div>
          {" "}
          <label>prix:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={handlerOnChangePrix} value={prix} />{" "}
        </div>{" "}
        <div>
          {" "}
          <input type="button" value="Ajouter" onClick={handlerAddArticle}/>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
        <div>
          {" "}
          <h3>liste Articles</h3>
          <ul>{Article}</ul>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

when I click on the button the function "handlerAddArticle" shows the article like that

[image]

The problem is that the list doesn't show when the function is being used

```
const handlerAddArticle = (e) => {
    setArticle(e.target.Article);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the item to the list

```
setArticle(prev => [...prev, {id,designation,prix}]);
```

use `map` to show items in the dom

```
 <ul>{Article.map(i => <><li>{i.id} | {i.designation}  | {i.prix} </li></>)}</ul>{" "}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kystmm?file=App.tsx)